# X509Certificate2 Info

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I would be able to retrieve some info about certificates such as hash algorithm and encryption algorithm, both of them as simple string, for instance:

- Hash Algorithm = `SHA-1`;
- Encryption Algorithm = `RSA`;

Is there some way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var hashAlgorithm = certificate.PrivateKey.SignatureAlgorithm;
var encryptionAlgorithm = certificate.PrivateKey.KeyExchangeAlgorithm;
```

They may not be *exactly* the sample values you've given, but that would be my starting point...